# Square Payment api integration angular and firebase serverless

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, square

I am creating a project using angular. In my project I am integrating square payment api and create charge using firebase. I know we can achieve with this server side easily, but my requirement is to do serverless. I already integrating angular side square api, but **I don't know how can I create charge without server**

```
cardNonceResponseReceived: function (errors, nonce, cardData)  {
        if (errors) {
          // Log errors from nonce generation to the Javascript console
          console.log("Encountered errors:");
          errors.forEach(function(error) {
            console.log('  ' + error.message);
          });
  
          return;
        }
  
        alert('Nonce received: ' + nonce); /* FOR TESTING ONLY */
  
        // Assign the nonce value to the hidden form field
        // document.getElementById('card-nonce').value = nonce;
        //needs to be extracted from the
        (<HTMLInputElement>document.getElementById('card-nonce')).value = nonce; //casting so .value will work
        //get this value from the database when the user is logged in
        (<HTMLInputElement>document.getElementById('sq-id')).value = "CBASEC8F-Phq5_pV7UNi64_kX_4gAQ";
  
        // POST the nonce form to the payment processing page
        (<HTMLFormElement>document.getElementById('nonce-form')).submit();
  
      },
```

Comment: Serverless does not make any sense. I guess something has to happen after someone has paid. Whether it is registering who paid or what that person paid for. Why else would you want a payment?

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question it looks like you create a CheckoutRequest and then call a CheckoutApi on the SquareConnect framework.

See this article for examples:
https://developer.squareup.com/blog/super-simple-serverless-ecommerce/

However, I would push back on the requirement for serverless only. That should not be a requirement that is set by your client or end user, nor should it be something that is not decided by you, as the development expert. Serverless payment is very dangerous and something that has huge potential for having security risks, PCI violations, and could violate OWASP principles.

[image]

Found here: https://medium.com/faun/how-to-create-a-serverless-payment-system-using-stripe-and-aws-lambda-3e532a5a3817

Even here they suggest that you should still add server side code to protect the sensitive data when doing serverless payment systems.